# running unitary tests in Spring throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

People, i have my multi-module project which is composed as:

```
example-backend-development
--> example-backend-development-domain
--> example-backend-development-service
```

I am configuring all data base config in my persistence properties, located inside resources folder from domain module. This file contains this:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sarasa_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=myPassword

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

So when i boot from my service i have no problem, because Spring Boot make a DataSource bean with these data. 
The problem comes when i want to create a unitary test inside Domain module.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DAOConfiguration.class)
public class ClientDAOTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientDAOTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private ClientDAO dao;

    @Test
    public void testFindClient() {
         LOGGER.info("Starting find all clients test");
         Page<Client> clients = this.dao.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 30, null));
       ...
    }
}
```

Where DAOConfiguration imports beans from PersisteConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.example.movies.domain"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Then, when i try to run testFindAllClient i have this exception:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
15:23:33.647 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@3e7cddcb testClass = ClientDAOTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@3db6fb5d testClass = ClientDAOTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.movies.domain.config.DAOConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Which i understand that is because i am not running it with Spring Boot and therefore, DAtaSource is not beeing created. Do you have any idea how can i solve this ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand that if i create manually the DataSource bean, the problem would be gone, but i prefer another solution

Comment: can you provide more details, properties in service, also ServicesConfiguration. file diagram of you current project. I think that you are not loading the correct property file.

Comment: What do you mean by not loading the correct property file? In PersistenceConfiguration i loading persistence.properties file, and in the ClientDAOTest i am loading ServicesConfiguration, which imports PersistenceConfiguration, so persistence.properties has to be called. I think that all of this problem is because for some reason spring-boot-data-jpa does not create DataSource bean, while spring-boot-starter-web does. Do you think im right ?

Comment: It is not right, spring-boot-data-jpa create the datasource you can check my configuration here https://gist.github.com/eddumelendez/976c30a5bc64ffcd5d74 Can you upoad your project or similar in order to reproduce?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i don't understand, regarding to this doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html, those properties from application.properties should start with spring., you are not invoking the same datasource builder that spring boot uses, are you? Regards!