# how can i load jpa properties to datasource in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot Data JPA and right now, i have this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.example.movies.domain"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(this.properties());
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties properties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", this.env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", this.env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", this.env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        return properties;

    }

}
```

And my persistence.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sarasa_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=myPassword

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

What i would to know is if there exists any way to load these JpaProperties automatically. I want that spring build it because right now,  if i add new jpa property in persistence.properties, then it wouldn't be noticed that change until i put that property in Properties object. So, do you know if is that possible? Regards!

Comment: Work with the framework not around the framework. Basically you can remove all of your configuration as Spring Boot will configure all that for you automatically. Basically what you want works by default but because you have worked around all that it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Yes , does work if i boot from the service. The problem is that i do not do that when i run my tests in domain layer... That is why am creating it manually

Comment: Don't do that, you should use the same mechanism and not work around it.

Comment: Please take a look to my other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222574/running-unitary-tests-in-spring-throws-nosuchbeandefinitionexception, i explained there what i am trying to say to you... before, I was configuring DataSource like the way you say but i had to change it when i started making tests...

Comment: No you don't you can use Spring Boot for testing as well (that is explained in the Spring Boot reference guide). You don't need different configurations, if you start going down that road you will end up working around Spring Boot in your testcases then what is the value of your test cases?

Comment: I really cannot understand, what should i do if i want to make tests? The only way i find is creating my DataSource manually. i know that that i should not do that, but i cannot avoid that error otherwise... Thanks for your response

Comment: Have you read the Spring Boot reference guide? That explains how to write tests, integration tests or web related test reusing the existing configuration.

Comment: Yes i've red that. However, i am a little confused. In my other question i have my test failing because of null DataSource and i don't understand what i am doing wrong. Documentation says that using SpringApplicationConfiguration gives me the additional Spring Boot features. So i don't know what i am missing. I would appreciate if you can give me any idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: But you aren't using `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` in your other post but `@ContextConfiguration` so it isn't using anything. Also you have explicitly configured JPA which is also provided. IMHO you tried to fix a problem by working around it instead of fixing the problem. Use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and point it to your application class. Then it should all work.

Comment: sorry. my mistake. in the other question i was using context-configuration but not anymore. I am using SpringApplicationConfiguration right now, pointing to DAOConfiguration. and y get  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource]

Comment: You must point it to a Spring boot starter class not any arbitrary class.

Comment: Ohhhh, but as i understand, i would have to use the "Application" class annotated with SpringBootApplication in service layer, and by "use" i mean use it as parameter on SpringApplicationConfiguration, am i right? If yes, then i have another problem, which is that my test is in domain layer and that Application class is in service layer, and domain don't know tha class because it doesn't have Service as dependency (But yes the other way around). What do i have to do in that case? Thanks and sory for being soo noob :P (i promise this is my last question)

Comment: Your application isn't about services it is about the application. Generally it is best placed in a top level package so that it covers multiple packages. Also packaging by layers instead of features is bad thing. (All of this is highly opinionated of course).

Comment: Nono, i expressed myself badly. My entire application is multi-module. And By domain and services layers i mean that i have a domain and service modules...  Service uses domain, but domain doesn't use service. Is that wrong ?

Comment: How do I make this work for spring.jpa.hibernate.generate_statistics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As M. Denium suggested you don't have to configure all these beans by yourself, SpringBoot will do that for you if you configure properties in application.properties.

And if you want to have separate datasource/jpa properties for testing then use environment profiles. You can create application-dev.properties, application-uat.properties, application-prod.properties to configure respective environment settings and activate the desired profile.

Take a look at the SpringBoot supported properties list at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

You can configure JPA properties as follows:

## JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)

```
spring.jpa.properties.*= # properties to set on the JPA connection
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=
spring.jpa.database=
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false # ignored by Hibernate, might be useful for other vendors
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy= # naming classname
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= # defaults to create-drop for embedded dbs
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true # if spring data repository support is enabled
```

If you follow this naming convention you don't have to configure beans yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But do you know why do i get org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] when i run my tests? I've already have the SpringApplicationConfiguration annotation pointing to DAOConfiguration.class (it has JPA implementations beans) and is still failing. I don't understand...

Comment: Is it working in main app and failing in JUnit tests only? If so can u post your JUnit code snippets?