Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration, required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found
I'm getting the below error when I try to run a Spring Boot web application. This is a web application which having thymeleaf and JPA.
Description:
Field checkListRepository in com.example.demo.service.CheckListService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Please find my Pom.xml and other dependencies are, spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-tomcat, pring-boot-starter-test, spring-boot-devtools
and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

Please find the Jpaconfig file which happing the jpa configurations
@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.example.demo.entity.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", basePackages = "com.example.demo.repository")
public abstract class JpaConfig {

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new 

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("repository.package.location");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }
    
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/research?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false");
    dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
    dataSource.setPassword( "root" );
    return dataSource;
}
    
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.demo");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(additionalProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());

    return transactionManager;
}
    
@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
       
    return properties;
}

MainApplication class which having the SpringBootApplication configurations
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EntityScan("com.example.demo.entity.CheckList")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo.repository")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

I've tried more than 100+ solutions on the net. Anyone would be helpful on this.

This is often because a starter or other dependency is missing. Are there any other errors/warning higher up in the logs? What about removing the JpaConfig class and doing the config with Spring Boot application.properties - spring.datasource and spring.jpa like this person did - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310988/how-can-i-load-jpa-properties-to-datasource-in-spring
